# Getting Node Address instead of Value in Binary Search Tree

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

I've got a basic binary search tree in Java. I'm trying to output the variable value, but all I get are addresses instead of the value itself. Also, can someone explain the relation between the code in my inOrderTraversal method and how it relates to the `display()` in my Node class even though I'm not calling it myself? All I'm calling in main is addNode and inorderTraversal.

The following is my code:

```
class Node {

int value;


Node leftChild;
Node rightChild;

Node(int value, String name) {

    this.value = value;
    this.name = name;

}

public int displayNode() {

    return value; 


}

}
```

InOrderTraversal Method:

```
public void inOrderTraverseTree(Node focusNode) {

    if (focusNode != null) {

        // Traverse the left node

        inOrderTraverseTree(focusNode.leftChild);

        // Visit the currently focused on node

        System.out.print(focusNode + " ");

        // Traverse the right node

        inOrderTraverseTree(focusNode.rightChild);

    }

}
```

Current Output: `Node@7852e922 Node@4e25154f Node@70dea4e Node@5c647e05 Node@33909752 Node@55f96302`
Desired Output: `5 10 15 20 25 30`

I'm pretty familiar with C++, was just self-learning Java and ran into these peculiar issues.

1. I'm only getting addresses not values of the nodes
2. What is the link between inOrderTraversal and display()? I'm not even calling the display() method myself.

Comment: override `toString()` of your `Node` Class and return only `value` in it.

Comment: @TheLostMind return just value gives me an error (wrong type returned). But if I return " " + value then it all works fine. Why is this so and what is the significance of toString in this data structure? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Use `return String.valueOf(value)` :). The reason for that error is *you are declaring that you will return a String (in method signature) but returning an int.

Comment: @TheLostMind Ah that works. Two things - why do we have to return a string, and what is the significance of this toString() method when we aren't even calling it? Sorry I'm super confused between the link of this method and inOrderTraversal(), which doesn't even call toString()?

Comment: @TheLostMind Alright, I understand we need to return a string in toString(). But what is the relevance/significance/link of the toString() method to inorderTraversal?

Comment: See, for *reference types*, if you do `System.out.println(myClassInstance)`, then *implicitly*, `toString()` method of `MyClass` will be invoked. and its default implementation (in `Object` class) is `getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())` . So to change the default behavior, you have to *override()* `toString()`. Check [the Object class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString())

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're printing an object, not its inner value (in other words, you're calling `toString()` implicitly).

In order to print the value, you should get the value from Node object:

```
System.out.print(focusNode.displayNode() + " ");
```

Also I would recommend you to rename your `displayNode()` method to `getValue()`, as it is better explains what the method does.

And if you want your method to print something when calling `System.out.println(object);`, you should override `toString()` method in Node class:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
  return this.value;
}
```

Then your code `System.out.print(focusNode + " ");` will display the node's value instead of object's address im memory.

Comment: Oh, in Java when we print an object, it implicitly called the toString() method?

Comment: Yes, `System.out.println(object)` is the same as `System.out.println(object.toString())`

Comment: Interesting. Well, it makes sense now. Thank you for your help!